# How do I replace the Li-ion battery in a Kenwood TM-741A?

Tags: kenwood, battery, repair

I'm in Dominica working with a donated TM-741A. The internal memory backup battery lasted just long enough for me to learn three things:

1. there's a backup battery;
2. it's dead;
3. there's no manual describing where it is in the radio, what type of battery it is or how to replace it.

Can anyone tell me how to replace it? I'm hoping one of the spare "watch" batteries in our SCUBA dive computers will fit.

Comment: What I could gather from https://www.radiomods.co.nz/kenwood/kenwoodtm741.html is that it's a lithium battery; since there's "resistors next to the battery", you'll most probably have to open the device anyway to find it. So, open up that device case, make a few good (as in: in-focus, well-lit) photos, and add them to your question!

Answer (score 3):

I found the [TM-741A service manual](http://www.repeater-builder.com/kenwood/pdfs/tm-641-741-svc-man.pdf). As shown on page 106, the battery can be seen looking into the case from the front after the display panel is removed. Luckily, the spare batteries from my dive computer will work; now I just have to open the radio and solder in a replacement!